# Regex to replace repeating characters in a certain condition

Tags: regex, vim

I'd like to replace something like this which is quite easy

```
----- -> =====
```

I can replace it in vim simply `:%s/-/=/g`.

But, what I want is to replace characters which starts with a regex `^` which means

```
-----  ->  =====
---    ->  ===
 --    ->   --    // stays the same
abc -  ->  abc -  // stays the same
```

Can I replace something like this using regex? I'm using vim, but any solution would be welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you need, but if you're trying to limit the replacement to lines that start with a '-', then you can do something like this:

```
g/^-/s/-/=/g
```

This will globally (first 'g') search for lines that start with '-', and then globally within that line (second 'g') replace '-' with '='.

Comment: You exactly understood my question! This is a perfect answer. Please tweak my question if you can.